# HTML UI broken of Extent Report for selenium in jenkins

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, selenium-extent-report

We are generating Extent report for selenium tests in jenkins but the HTML UI gets broken very frequently. We then run below commands in Script Console section under Manage Jenkins and it works at that time. But, it's just a temporary solution for it.

```
System.clearProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP");

System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "sandbox allow-scripts; default-src 'self'; script-src * 'unsafe-eval'; img-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; font-src *");
```

Also, in Extent report, the left side tabs as shown in below image are not working when we are clicking on them. But when we download Zip, the tabs are working in HTML doc present.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkZfA.png)

Could anyone please suggest permanent solution of above 2 issues?

Note: Jenkins is running on docker.